# Best way to sum concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, biginteger

I am trying to compute some big numbers. In order to speed up computation, I would like to make use of multithreading. Each thread should calculate a number and in the end a sum is calculated.

I once saw something that worked with a `SumThread` and a `Collector` that looked as follows:

```
public BigInteger compute(int p) {
    Collector c = new Collector(p);

    for(T element : Collection<T> bigCollection) {
        new SumThread(c) {

            @Override
            protected void doTheJob() {
                long big = someVeryComplexCalculation(element, ...); //n!
                receive(BigInteger.valueOf(big));
            }

        }
    }

    if(collector.isReady())
        return collector.getResult();

    return null;
}

public class Collector {

    private int numberOfProcesses;
    private int numberOfAllowedProcesses;
    private BigInteger result;

    public Collector(int n) {
        numberOfAllowedProcesses = n;
        numberOfProcesses = 0;
        result = BigInteger.ZERO;
    }

    synchronized public void enter() throws InterruptedException {
        if (numberOfProcesses == numberOfAllowedProcesses) wait();
        numberOfProcesses++;
    }

    synchronized public void leave() {
        numberOfProcesses--;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized public void register(BigInteger v) {
        result = result.add(v);
    }

    synchronized public boolean isReady() throws InterruptedException {
        while (numberOfProcesses > 0) wait();
        return true;
    }

    ...
}

public abstract class SumThread extends Thread {

    private Collector collector;

    public SumThread(Collector c) throws InterruptedException {
        collector = c;
        collector.enter();
    }

    abstract protected void doTheJob(); //complex calculations can be done in here

    public void receive(BigInteger t) {
        collector.register(t);
    }

    public void run() {
        doTheJob();
        collector.leave();
    }
}
```

I thought I could easily outperform this by using [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead of making new `Thread`s constantly like:

```
public BigInteger compute(int p) {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(p);
    Future<BigInteger>[] futures = new Future<BigInteger>[bigCollection.size()];
    int i = 0;

    for(T element : Collection<T> bigCollection) {
        futures[i++] = p.submit(new Callable<BigInteger>() {

            @Override
            public BigInteger call() {
                long big = someVeryComplexCalculation(element, ...); //n!
                return BigInteger.valueOf(big);
            }

        }
    }

    // or with ExecutorCompletionService, but the loop remains I guess
    BigInteger res = BigInteger.ZERO
    for(Future<BigInteger> f : futures)
        res = res.add(f.get());

    return res;
}
```

This code didn't manage to outperform the `SumThread`-`Collector` solution however. I've also seen things about `LongAdder` for instance, but I would need some adder for `BigInteger`s...

My question thus is: what is the best way to calculate a sum concurrently? Is it one of the above or is there a completely different (but better) way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are mentioned `LongAdder` which was added in Java-8 and use effectively-final variables, I assume that you are using Java-8. In this version the best way to solve your task is to use the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#executing_streams_in_parallel):

```
BigInteger result = bigCollection.parallelStream()
                     .map(e -> BigInteger.valueOf(someVeryComplexCalculation(e, ...)))
                     .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);
```

Your problem is the classical map-reduce task where you should transform each element of some collection, then combine the results of the individual transformations into the final result. The Stream API is capable to parallelize such tasks quite effectively without any manual work. In Oracle JDK the tasks are executed in the [common ForkJoinPool pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) which by default creates as many threads as many CPU cores you have.

Comment: This is quite effective indeed! Just out of curiousity: are there any possibilities to apply this to instances of `Iterable<T>` for example? Is there a way to zip streams? (e.g.: _complexCalculation() = part1()*part2() therefore I would like to map part1() on bigCollection and part2() and parallelly merge the results from both resulting streams with multiplication_)

Comment: @MrTsjolder, in order to process the stream in parallel, your stream source (Iterable or whatever) must provide a spliterator which can split your source well. If you doubt about your source, you can just copy the content of `Iterable<T>` to the `ArrayList<T>`. As for zipping, I cannot answer without seeing the exact source code. You may ask a different question providing all the necessary details (use "java-stream" tag, I always monitor it).

Answer (score 2):

Tou have two solutions:

In first, I would propose to use Fork-Join Framework from JDK7 for this task:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html
- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/java-7-forkjoin-framework-example.html

You would need to implement an RecursiveTask

As a second solution (JDK8) would be to use pararell stream, just as @tagir-valeev has proposed.

In both cases it depends what you are in for, and what Java version you are using.