# Is there a way to zip two streams?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

This question arrose from the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134456/best-way-to-sum-concurrently/32134573?noredirect=1#comment52162136_32134573) where map and reduce were suggested to calculate a sum concurrently.

In that question there's a `complexCalculation(e)`, but now I was wondering how to parallellise even more, by splitting the calculation in two parts, so that `complexCalculation(e)` = `part1(e)` * `part2(e)`. I wonder whether it would be possible to calculate part1 and part2 on a collection concurrently (using `map()` again) and then zip the two resulting streams so that the ith element of both streams is combined with the function * so that the resulting stream equals the stream that can be gotten by mapping `complexCalculation(e)` on that collection. In code this would look like:

```
Stream map1 = bigCollection.parallelStream().map(e -> part1(e));
Stream map2 = bigCollection.parallelStream().map(e -> part2(e));
// preferably map1 and map2 are computed concurrently...
Stream result = map1.zip(map2, (e1, e2) -> e1 * e2);

result.equals(bigCollection.map(e -> complexCalculation(e))); //should be true
```

So my question is: does there exist some functionality like the `zip` function I tried to describe here?

Comment: Zip was discussed here [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

parallelStream() is guarenteed to complete in the order submitted.  This means you cannot assume that two parallelStreams can be zipped together like this.

Your original `bigCollection.map(e -> complexCalculation(e))` is likely to be faster unless your collection is actually smaller than the number of CPUs you have.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to parallelize `part1` and `part2` (for example your bigCollection has very few elements, less than CPU cores), you can do the following trick. Suppose you have two methods `part1` and `part2` in the current class:

```
public long part1(Type t) { ... }
public long part2(Type t) { ... }
```

Create a stream of two functions created from these methods and process it in parallel like this:

```
bigCollection.parallelStream()
    .map(e -> Stream.<ToLongFunction<Type>>of(this::part1, this::part2)
            .parallel()
            .mapToLong(fn -> fn.applyAsLong(e)).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a*b))
    .// continue the outer stream operations
```

However it's very rare case. As @PeterLawrey noted if your outer collection is big enough, no need to parallelize `part1` and `part2`. Instead you will handle separate elements in parallel.